# How can i develop the PagerSlidingTabStrip with images in android?

Tags: android, imageview, pagertabstrip

I am using the PagerSlidingTabStrip in myapp .In this titles are setting fine but images are not setting tabstrip .I searched alot in google but didn't get the correct result.But this is very important for me.

Please see screenshot below 
[image]

Advance thanks to all.

Comment: you can write you own SlingTabLayout.

Answer (score 6):

I was also interested doing same as yours, Finally I did it for you.

Import 'SlidingTabsBasic' demo from android-sdk sample or download it from google android samples from [Here](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html).

1.create custom_tab.xml with only a TextView
2.In 'SlidingTabsBasicFragment.class' do below changes:

-add this code in onViewCreated()

```
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

-in SamplePagerAdapter class, replace this function code

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    //return "Item " + (position + 1);
    Drawable image = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
```

If you have done it properly, You will get something like this:

[image: Tab Strip]

Hope this will help!

Comment: interesting SpannableString!. i never thought of this. This is much easier than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Well it wasn't hard looking at the code of `SlidingTabLayout` I have commented few lines of code. The code is self explanatory i guess.

Well you can customize it according to your needs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
    int prepage;
    int currpage;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
      //  mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

//            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
 //           }
//
//            if (tabView == null) {
//                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
//            }
//
//            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
//                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
//            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//            tabT itleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          //  TextView tab = (TextView) mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
           // tab.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

SlidingTabStrip.java

```
import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;

    private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
    private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

        mDefaultBottomBorderColor = Color.YELLOW;
        //setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
               // DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
                ? mCustomTabColorizer
                : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0) {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor) {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }


            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                    height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;



        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.customslidingtablayout.MainActivity" >

   <com.example.customslidingtablayout.SlidingTabLayout

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                              
                android:background="@color/red" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tab_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
     mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
     mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

     mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_indicator);
     mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
     mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
     mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for repose but i didn't SlidingTabLayout not added showing the errors .please provide SlidingTabLayout.java file

Comment: please provide the FragmentAdapter.java file

Comment: is it FragmentAdapter.java calss

Comment: @Ashok that's just a adapter for your view pager

Answer (score 0):

I ever writed a project about this topic. Here is my [project](https://github.com/LittlePanpc/PagerSlidingTabStrip), take a look, maybe you will be inspired.