# Tablayout with icons only

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I am using design support to create tabs. I am also using `ViewPager` for swipable tabs.

Now, I don't know how to use only icons instead of texts in tabs. I tried finding out but didn't get any success.

My code:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTablayout();
}

private void setupTablayout() {
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        mFragmentTitleList.get(position)
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new frag(), "CAT");
    adapter.addFrag(new frag(), "DOG");
    adapter.addFrag(new frag(), "BIRD");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: try spannable texts. try my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534420/how-can-i-develop-the-pagerslidingtabstrip-with-images-in-android/29535378#29535378). Vote up if it helps.

Answer (score 165):

One approach is setting the icons after [TabLayout.setupWithViewPager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabsFromPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)) method.

```
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
}
```

Comment: In my case, this solution displays both icon and text, which is actually what I need :-)

Comment: This will show text if you override `getPageTitle` in your pager adapter, otherwise only the icon will be shown

Comment: this solution not working in `27.1.0` , but if i override `getPageTitle` then only title shows instead

Comment: it does if you do an adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before

Answer (score 27):

The tutorial shown in the following link should cover what you want. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-icons-to-tablayout

I copied the relevant section below.

Add Icons to TabLayout

Currently, the TabLayout class does not provide a clean abstraction model that allows for icons in your tab. There are many posted workarounds, one of which is to return a SpannableString, containing your icon in an ImageSpan, from your PagerAdapter's getPageTitle(position) method as shown in the code snippet below:

```
private int[] imageResId = {
        R.drawable.ic_one,
        R.drawable.ic_two,
        R.drawable.ic_three
};

// ...

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    // return tabTitles[position];
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
```

By default, the tab created by TabLayout sets the textAllCaps property to be true, which prevents ImageSpans from being rendered. You can override this behavior by changing the tabTextAppearance property.

```
  <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Tab wont show any icons, even setting `textAllCaps = false` does nothing

Comment: When i try to build my code, i get this error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabTextAppearance' in package 'android'

Comment: One thing I've noticed with this technique that the text size will vary up when the icons are visible.

Comment: Thank you guy, the property "textAllCaps" solved my issue with the icons.

Answer (score 25):

In new version of `TabLayout`, google added `TabItem` which easily can add Icon through your XML with following code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
         app:tabMode="fixed"
         app:tabBackground="@color/red"
         app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
         app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple"
         app:tabPadding="2dp"
         app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
         app:tabMinWidth="64dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <!--add height and width to TabItem -->
     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem 
             android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Comment: this is actual way to add icons :)

Comment: If used with a view pager, teh view pager calls removeAllTabs() which removes any tab elements added via the layout file.

Comment: Doesn't work, as soon as a PagerAdapter is used the tabs are reset, and only titles are shown, taken from the adapter.

Answer (score 21):

try this

```
    public class GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.home_ic,
            R.drawable.biz_ic,
            R.drawable.network_ic,
            R.drawable.offers_ic,
            R.drawable.message_ic_b
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_global_hub);
        tab();
    }
    public void tab(){
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);

    }
    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new GlHubFragment(),"HOME");
        adapter.addFrag(new BizForumFragment(), "BIZ FORUM");
        adapter.addFrag(new NetworkFragment(), "NETWORK");
        adapter.addFrag(new MessagesFragment(), "MESSAGEs");
        adapter.addFrag(new OfferFragmentActivity(), "OFFER");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mfragmentlist =new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mfragmentlist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mfragmentlist.size();
        }
        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment,String title){
            mfragmentlist.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In `TabLayout`, setting icon is easy:

`getPageTitle(position)` should return `null` (if you don't want title to show).

Next :

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(resId);

tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(resId);

......
```

Comment: I tried this and the icon is in the above of text.How to make icon to the left of the text?

Comment: in my case , if i leave getPageTitle() as it is then...icon is displayed next to title...May be title text is too large in your case.

Answer (score 5):

None of these methods are elegant when using TabLayout as the ViewPager "decor" scenario. [TabLayout Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)  Here is a simple extension of TabLayout and PagerAdapter that provides a simple drop in replacement for TabLayout that should be able to be used in either scenario without manually adding icons outside of the TabLayout class and following the usage of PagerAdapter to get the tab information.

```
/**
 * Created by JDL on 1/18/2017.
 */
public class TabLayoutExt extends TabLayout {

    protected ViewPager mViewPager;

    public abstract static class TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        /**
         * This method may be called by the TabLayout to obtain an icon drawable
         * to for the specified tab. This method may return null
         * indicating no tab icon for this page. The default implementation returns
         * null.
         *
         * @param position The position of the title requested
         * @return A drawable icon for the requested page
         */
        public Drawable getPageIcon(Context context, int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public TabLayoutExt(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TabLayoutExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TabLayoutExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        //Cover the implicit setup in TabLayout
        if (mViewPager == null) {
            final ViewParent vp = getParent();
            if (vp instanceof ViewPager) {
                mViewPager = (ViewPager)vp;
            }

        }
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, int position, boolean setSelected) {
        if (mViewPager != null && mViewPager.getAdapter() instanceof TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter) {
            Drawable icon = ((TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).getPageIcon(getContext(),position);
            tab.setIcon(icon);
        }
        super.addTab(tab,position,setSelected);

    }

    @Override
    public void setupWithViewPager(@Nullable ViewPager viewPager, boolean autoRefresh) {
        mViewPager = viewPager;
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, autoRefresh);
    }
}
```

So all that needs be done is extend `TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter` instead of `PageAdapter` and implement `getPageIcon(Context,int)` instead of or in addition to title. The drop in `TabLayoutExt` in your XML file, instead of the normal `TabLayout`. This could be extended for further modifying the tab, either with a custom view instead or something else.

Answer (score 5):

With the [`TabLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use:

- the method [**`setIcon`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab.html#setIcon(int)) to define the resourceId
- the method [**`setTabLabelVisibility`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab.html#settablabelvisibility) to set the [`TAB_LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.html#TAB_LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED).

Something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<tabLayout.getTabCount();i++){

   tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(iconResId);
   tabLayout.getTabAt(i).
        setTabLabelVisibility(TabLayout.TAB_LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found to use icons is to use Tablayout.Tab.setIcon(drawable). This also makes it easy to highlight the selected icon. If you want to do this, follow these steps.

Step 1.
Add your images to the res.mipmap folders. (mipmap-mdpi, hdpi etc.) Judging by the other answers here it's also fine to put then in the res.drawable folders.

Step 2.
Call setIcon on all your tabs after setting up your TabLayout and ViewPager. I did this in my AdapterTabs to keep the Activity tidy.
So in your activity do this:

```
    tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterTabs = new AdapterTabs(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, tablayout, viewPager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterTabs);
    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    adapterTabs.setTabIcons();
```

and in your AdapterTabs, which should extend FragmentPagerAdapter, put your setTabIcons() method.

```
    public void setTabTitlesToIcons() {
    Drawable icon1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_1);
    Drawable icon2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_2);
    Drawable icon3 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_3);
    Drawable icon1Hilighted = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_1_selected);
    Drawable icon2Hilighted = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_2_selected);
    Drawable icon3Hilighted = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_3_selected);

    icons.add(icon1);
    icons.add(icon2);
    icons.add(icon3);
    iconsHilighted.add(icon1Hilighted);
    iconsHilighted.add(icon2Hilighted);
    iconsHilighted.add(icon3Hilighted);

    for(int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(iconsSelected.get(i));
        }
        else {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to store a reference to the two lists 'icons' and 'iconsHilighted'. You'll need them later. Also store a reference to the TabLayout and the ViewPager which you passed in from the activity.

Step 3.
Make sure AdapterTabs.getPageTitle() returns null.
At this point, if you run it you should see that the first icon is highlighted.

Step 4.
Implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener in AdapterTabs and add that listener to your viewPager

```
    public AdapterTabs(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments, TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager viewPager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.context = context;
    this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
    this.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    tabs.add(fragments.get(0));
    tabs.add(fragments.get(1));
    tabs.add(fragments.get(2));
}
```

Step 5.
Update the icons in the tabs in the onPageSelected callback in your AdapterTabs.

```
    @Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
        if(i == position) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(iconsSelected.get(i));
        }
        else {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should see the hilighted icon being updated when you change tabs.

Comment: You have special drawables for this called selectors in which you can configure different states.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but why are the icons removed once you select a new TAB that is not in cache? They are not staying and therefore one must reinsert them in .onPageSelected. Really stupid  solution. A bug?

Comment: I think you need to work on your soft skills @carl. Hence, no further comments from me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this this will definitely work .

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.single,
        R.drawable.multiple};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Choose contact");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    tab();
}


public void tab(){
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Login());
    adapter.addFragment(new Register());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, defining the icons in the TabLayout does not work when using a PagerAdapter. For those using Kotlin, one workaround is to create an extension function like this:

```
fun TabLayout.setupWithViewPagerAndKeepIcons(viewPager : ViewPager?) {
    val icons =  mutableListOf<Drawable?>()
    repeat(tabCount) {
        icons.add(getTabAt(it)?.icon)
    }
    setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    repeat(tabCount) {
        getTabAt(it)?.setIcon(icons.get(it))
    }
}
```

Then in the layout.xml add your icons to the TabLayout:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Finally, use the extension function to setup the TabLayout with a ViewPager.

```
tab_layout.setupWithViewPagerAndKeepIcons(view_pager)
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is create new table by setting Icon on tablayout. below code will create two tab with icon only. use this code on onCreate() method

```
 tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.order_tablayout);
 tablayout.addTab( tablayout.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp)) );
 tablayout.addTab( tablayout.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_like2_fille_white_24dp)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a ViewPager. This is how I have a tab with an icon only and no text.

```
TabLayout tabs...

TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(0);
tab.setText("");
tab.setIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon);
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best answer for all cases, but what I found did not solve my problem yet.

After having a look at Androids implementation of `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager pager)` I came up with a solution using just listeners.

The layout structure:

```
| LinearLayout (vertical)
|-- TabLayout (width: match_parent)
|---- TabItem (without text, just icons)
|---- TabItem
|---- ...
|-- ViewPager
```

Code for the both listeners:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, positionOffset, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
        if (tab != null) {
            tab.select();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Have a look at the `tabLayout.setScrollPosition` call inside `OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled` for the more or less good moving of the indicator while scrolling.

This may not work if the TabLayout's width is not set to match_parent (or must be scrollable).