# How to change text title in viewpager to image

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager, pagertitlestrip

I have a viewpager tab in my app that uses text to display the title. I initially followed a tutorial to make it text, but now I want it to be icons. I've already seen answers to this question, but I'm struggling to implement them into my code.

**This is the code that gives the tabs their title**

```
  package com.khumomashapa.notes.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R
import com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments.FileViewerFragment
import com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments.RecordFragment

class AudioRecorderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var tabs: PagerSlidingTabStrip? = null
    private var pager: ViewPager? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_recorder)
        pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
        pager!!.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tabs = findViewById<View>(R.id.tabs) as PagerSlidingTabStrip
        tabs!!.setViewPager(pager)
        val toolbar = findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        toolbar.popupTheme = R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                val i = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    inner class MyAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(
        fm!!
    ) {
        private val titles = arrayOf(getString(R.string.tab_title_record), getString(R.string.tab_title_saved_recordings)
        )

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    return RecordFragment.newInstance(position)
                }
                1 -> {
                    return FileViewerFragment.newInstance(position)
                }
            }
            return null!!
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return titles.size
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return titles[position]
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOG_TAG = AudioRecorderActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

**This is what the titles currently look like**

[image: This is what my viewpager titles currenlty look like]

Comment: Could [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892545/tablayout-with-icons-only) be what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I'm having a bit of trouble using those for my code. Mine is in Kotlin and the answers are in Java. I'll post my entire code this time.

Comment: If you have problems understanding the differences between Java and Kotlin, please ask a new question with particular problems and what you have tried and the community will help you. Also, Kotlin and Java aren't that different although I can see how the syntax may appear foreign to a new Kotlin developer. Java is, after all, the language that Kotlin compiles to (JavaBytecode in the end), so it's important as a Kotlin developer to have a decent understanding of how it operates, for some of its peculiarities, may affect Kotlin (and do so on a regular basis).

Comment: Additionally, if you PASTE Java code into a kotlin file (and I'm not encouraging you to copy-paste what you see on StackOverflow), Android Sudio will ask you if you want to convert the code to Kotlin. It will do a _decent_ job that may help you clarify how some particular construct is made in Kotlin. From there, LINT suggestions should help you make it more kotlin-like (if needed).

Comment: Thank you. I've worked with kotlin for so long that I've forgotten even the simplest of syntax difference. This is the only time I've encountered this issue. I also prefer not to always copy java code and convert to kotlin. I almost always know what to do, it's just that sometimes I run into problems. I'll keep giving this a look, but I know I'll fix my problem

Comment: I'm sure you will, if not, feel free to ask specific (and simple) questions in [Android Help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help) chat. Keep in mind i'm not always there and sometimes it's empty, but if you leave a question, i'll eventually look into it (or maybe someone else will) :)

Comment: I'll do so. Thank you once again for your help. Enjoy the rest of your day/evening