# How to put icon in SlidingTab?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How i can put icon in my tab using SlidingTabLayout. I just want to change the Titles into Icon. Please help me on how to do it.

Here is the code
ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        OrderTab ordertab = new OrderTab();
        return ordertab;
    }
    else if(position==1)     // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        ViewOrderTab viewordertab = new ViewOrderTab();
        return viewordertab;
    }
    else
    {
        OrderStatus orderstatus = new OrderStatus();
        return orderstatus;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}


public static interface FirstShot
{
    public void onFirstShot();
}

}
```

SlidingTabLayout.java

```
package com.example.work.mcoatorderingapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give      constant feedback as to
* the user's scroll progress.
* <p>
* To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
* {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
* {@link #setViewPager(ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is  being used for.
* <p>
* The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to  provide an array of colors
* via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)}. The
* alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
* which color is used for any individual position.
* <p>
* The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link   #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
* providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
 /**
  * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
  * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
  */
 public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;
private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {

    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);

}

public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
    mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
 * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
 * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
 * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
 *
 * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
 */
public void OnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 *
 * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}

/**
 * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
 * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
 */
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
 * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    textView.setAllCaps(true);

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }

        tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
        tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
    }
}




public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
    mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

The Fragments are OrderTab.java the same code with ViewOrderTab.java and OrderStatus.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


 public class OrderStatus extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.orderstatus_list,container,false);
      return v;
  }
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
EditText search;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"Order Product", "Cart", "Order Status"};
int Numboftabs = 3;
String titlebar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs=(SlidingTabLayout)

    findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer()

                           {
                               @Override
                               public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {


                                   return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);

                               }
                           }

   );
    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420293/android-slidingtablayout-with-icons

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534420/how-can-i-develop-the-pagerslidingtabstrip-with-images-in-android/29535374#29535374

Comment: @Raghunandan Sir i want to use the code above. I want to set an icon to  tabs using the code above.

Comment: @Raghunandan Because I'm using 3 Layout Fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.ic_home,
            R.drawable.ic_my_timeline,
            R.drawable.ic_my_pages,
            R.drawable.ic_my_groups,
            R.drawable.ic_liked_pages
    };

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
     image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
     SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
     ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
     sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
     return sb;
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}
```

in your ViewPagerAdapter class.

**EDIT1:**

In your activity change

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
```

to

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
```

Then in your ViewPagerAdapter following changes are needed.

```
Context mContext;
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}
```

**EDIT2:**

try extending FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter in your ViewPagerAdapter.

In your main activity code should be this:

```
tabs=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
```

Here is custom_tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

hope this helps!

Comment: You have to pass Your activity's context to your Adapter when you initilize it.

Comment: i will post my MainActivity

Comment: private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.ic_home,
            R.drawable.ic_my_timeline,
            R.drawable.ic_my_pages,
            R.drawable.ic_my_groups,
            R.drawable.ic_liked_pages
    }; pass your images in your array properly then it will show here i have give 5 image resolution to show 5 tabs

Comment: should i edit Charsequence in my activity? check my Charseqence Titles in my activity

Comment: I put 3 images because i use 3 tabs

Comment: Try EDIT2 solution pls

Comment: One again Thanks a lot :D

Comment: how to change icon color on pressed state?