# Display icons on FragmentPagerAdapter tabs

Tags: android, tabs, xamarin

*This example is created in Xamarin using C#, if you know the answer in Java, I'll be able to convert it into C# too*

I'm using the [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to display three different Fragments as Tabs. I'm able to display some text in the Tab headers like this:

```
public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
{
    return new Java.Lang.String("Tab: " + position);
}
```

This works just fine: I'm seeing three tabs with titles `Tab: 0`, `Tab: 1` and `Tab: 2`.

Now, I want to replace the text with some icons. I'm trying to do that the same was as with the [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534420/how-can-i-develop-the-pagerslidingtabstrip-with-images-in-android/29535378#29535378), using a `SpannableString` & `ImageSpan` .

```
public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
{
    var image = Application.Context.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.icon);
    image.SetBounds(0, 0, image.IntrinsicWidth, image.IntrinsicHeight);

    var spannableString = new Android.Text.SpannableString("[icon]");
    var imageSpan = new Android.Text.Style.ImageSpan(image, Android.Text.Style.SpanAlign.Bottom);
    spannableString.SetSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Android.Text.SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
    return spannableString;
}
```

Sadly, what I'm seeing right now is three times `[icon]` as headers. It looks like as if the icons aren't added to the headers at all.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the tab created by TabLayout sets the textAllCaps property to be true, which prevents ImageSpans from being rendered. You can override this behavior by changing the tabTextAppearance property.

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
      <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Then you can add the MyCustomTabLayout Style to your TabLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
 android:id="@+id/tabs"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
```

Comment: I tried this and applied the style to the Tablayout like this
android:textAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
But it di not work I just got the '[icon]' String

Comment: You are right. You need to apply the style to the TabLayout. I wil edit my answer.

Comment: what the hell, OP asked for icons, and the answer is about the text, what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Just Like Youp Said we have to apply the above style as

```
style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
```

but not

```
android:textAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
```

Refer this for more information
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout